# Find least positive integer $n$ which satisfies the condition

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

**Find least positive integer $n$ which satisfies the condition**

- $| {0.5}^{\frac{1}{n}}-1|<10^{-3} $
- $0.9^{n}<10^{-3}$

What I have tried is I have split the first inequality  took log on both side .. but I came to know it is getting complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the second one we get by taking the logarithm $$n\ln\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)<\ln(10^{-3}$$ therefore $$n>\frac{10^{-3}}{\ln(0.9)}$$
we get $$n\geq 66$$
for the second one we get
$$n>\frac{\ln(0.5)}{\ln(1-10^{-3})}$$ therefore $$n\geq 693$$

Comment: This i know , but i want to get the least value in terms of integer

Answer (score -1):

\begin{array}{c}
   | 0.5^{\frac 1n}-1| < \frac{1}{1000}\\
   1-\frac{1}{1000} < 0.5^{\frac 1n} < 1+\frac{1}{1000} \\
   \frac{999}{1000} < 0.5^{\frac 1n} < \frac{1001}{1000} \\
   \log 999 - 3 < -\frac 1n \log \dfrac 12 < \log 1001 - 3 \\
   \log 999 - 3 < \frac 1n \log 2 < \log 1001 - 3 \\
   \dfrac{\log 999 - 3}{\log 2} < \frac 1n < \dfrac{\log 1001 - 3}{\log 2} \\
\end{array}

$\dfrac{\log 999 - 3}{\log 2} < 0 < \frac 1n$ is always true for positive integer values of $n$.

\begin{align}
   \frac 1n < \dfrac{\log 1001 - 3}{\log 2} \\
   n > \dfrac{\log 2}{\log 1001 - 3} \\
   n > 693.49\dots \\
\end{align}

The least integer value of $n$ is $n = 694$